# Spring active Mq Configuration for multiple queue

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-framework-beans

I want  to Send some *xml*  file to an active Mq queue, and receive from a receiver class . I did it , but  there is a problem to send response message from receiver class to an other queue to get the message in producer class. I tried to change Spring configuration to add new queue but it doesn't working .
Here is My  configuration.
Can any one help me to Solve my issue ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="messageQueue1" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="15000" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="messageDestination" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="springJmsProducer" class="rfid.Producer">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I can't see any route in your xml? If i understood u correctly you should create route under  `<camelContext id="somebeanid" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">`

Comment: This is a confusing question, can you try to better explain